# System.InvalidOperationException Error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to make a soundboard app with a record feature but I am running into a System.InvalidOperationException when I click 'record' also for some reason my sounds are not playing.

Animals.xaml :

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="SoundBoard.Animals"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/SampleData.xaml}"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="RotateCirlce" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <DoubleAnimation
                Duration="0:0:4"
                To="360"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransfrom).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)"
                Storyboard.TargetName="ReelGrid"
                d:IsOptimized="True" />

        </Storyboard>


    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <!--LayoutRoot contains the root grid where all other page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <phone:Panorama Title="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle,
            Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">

            <!--Panorama item one-->
            <phone:PanoramaItem Header="Animals">
                <Grid>
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="463" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Source="/Assets/cat.jpg"/>
                </Grid>
            </phone:PanoramaItem>

            <!--Panorama item two-->
            <phone:PanoramaItem Header="Sounds">
                <phone:LongListSelector
                    Margin="0,0,-12,0" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Animals.Items}"
                    LayoutMode="Grid"
                    GridCellSize="150,150"                  
                    >
                    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">

                                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                      Width="40" Height="40" Margin="0,6,6,0">
                                    <Ellipse Stroke="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" 
                                             StrokeThickness="3" />
                                    <Image Source="Assets/AppBar/Play.png" />


                                </Grid>

                                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                                               Margin="6,0,0,6"/>

                                </StackPanel>

                            </Grid>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector>
            </phone:PanoramaItem>

            <!--Panorama item three-->
            <phone:PanoramaItem Header="Record">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
                        <MediaElement x:Name="AudioPlayer" AutoPlay="False" />

                        <StackPanel>
                            <ToggleButton Content="Record"
                                          Checked="RecordAudioChecked"
                                          Unchecked="RecordAudioUnchecked"/>
                            <Grid Width="200" 
                                  Height="200" 
                                  Name="ReelGrid"
                                  RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                    <CompositeTransform />
                                </Grid.RenderTransform>


                                <Ellipse Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />

                                <Ellipse Height="20"
                                         Width="20"
                                         Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
                                <Rectangle Height="20"
                                           Width="20"
                                           Margin="0,20,0,20"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                           Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />

                                <Rectangle Height="20"
                                           Width="20"
                                           Margin="0,20,0,20"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                           Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />

                                <Rectangle Height="20"
                                           Width="20"
                                           Margin="0,0,20,0"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                           Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />

                                <Rectangle Height="20"
                                           Width="20"
                                           Margin="20,0,0,0"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                           Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />

                            </Grid>
                            <Button Name="PlayAudio" Content="Play" Click="PlayAudioClick" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </phone:PanoramaItem>

        </phone:Panorama>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

and the Animals.xaml.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Resources;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using SoundBoard.Resources;
using Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Audio;
using Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Audio.Helpers;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls;
using SoundBoard.ViewModels;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace SoundBoard
{
    public partial class Animals : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private MicrophoneRecorder _recorder = new MicrophoneRecorder();
        private IsolatedStorageFileStream _audioStream;
        private string _tempFileName = "tempWav.wav";


        public Animals()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = App.ViewModel;

            BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }
        // Load data for the ViewModel Items
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
            {
                App.ViewModel.LoadData();
            }
        }

        private void LongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            LongListSelector selector = sender as LongListSelector;

            // verifying our sender is actually a LongListSelector
            if (selector == null)
                return;

            SoundData data = selector.SelectedItem as SoundData;

            // verifying our sender is actually SoundData
            if (data == null)
                return;

            if (File.Exists(data.FilePath))
            {
                AudioPlayer.Source = new Uri(data.FilePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            }
            else
            {
                using (var storageFolder = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(data.FilePath, FileMode.Open, storageFolder))
                    {
                        AudioPlayer.SetSource(stream);
                    }
                }
            }

            selector.SelectedItem = null;
        }

        private void BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
        {
            ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

            ApplicationBarIconButton recordAudioAppBar =
                new ApplicationBarIconButton();

            recordAudioAppBar.IconUri = new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/Save.png", UriKind.Relative);
            recordAudioAppBar.Text = AppResources.AppBarSave;

            recordAudioAppBar.Click += recordAudioAppBar_Click;

            ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(recordAudioAppBar);
            ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;

        }

        void recordAudioAppBar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InputPrompt fileName = new InputPrompt();

            fileName.Message = "What should we call the sound?";

            fileName.Completed += FileNameCompleted;

            fileName.Show();

        }

        private void FileNameCompleted(object sender, PopUpEventArgs<string, PopUpResult> e)
        {
            if (e.PopUpResult == PopUpResult.Ok)
            {

                // Create a sound data object

                SoundData soundData = new SoundData();
                soundData.FilePath = string.Format("/customAudio/{0}.wav", DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
                soundData.Title = e.Result;

                // Save the wav file into the DIR /customAudio/

                using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (!isoStore.DirectoryExists("/customAudio/"))
                        isoStore.CreateDirectory("/customAudio/");

                    isoStore.MoveFile(_tempFileName, soundData.FilePath);
                }


                // Add the SoundData to App.ViewModel.CustomSounds

                App.ViewModel.CustomSounds.Items.Add(soundData);

                // Save the list of CustomSounds to isolatedStorage.ApplicationSettings

                var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(App.ViewModel.CustomSounds);

                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[SoundModel.CustomSoundKey] = data;
                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();

                // We'll need to modify sound model to retrieve CustomSounds
                //from isolatedStorage.ApplicationSettings

                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            }
        }

        private void RecordAudioChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PlayAudio.IsEnabled = false;
            ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;
            RotateCirlce.Begin();
            _recorder.Start();
        }

        private void RecordAudioUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _recorder.Stop();

            SaveTempAudio(_recorder.Buffer);

            RotateCirlce.Stop();
            PlayAudio.IsEnabled = true;
            ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;

        }

        private void SaveTempAudio(MemoryStream buffer)
        {
            //defensive...
            if (buffer == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Attempting a save on empty sound buffer.");

            //Clean out hold on audioStream
            if (_audioStream != null)
            {
                AudioPlayer.Stop();
                AudioPlayer.Source = null;

                _audioStream.Dispose();
            }

            var bytes = buffer.GetWavAsByteArray(_recorder.SampleRate);

            using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {

                if (isoStore.FileExists(_tempFileName))
                    isoStore.DeleteFile(_tempFileName);

                _tempFileName = string.Format("{0}.wav", DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());


                _audioStream = isoStore.CreateFile(_tempFileName);
                _audioStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                //Play ...  SetSource of a mediaElement
                AudioPlayer.SetSource(_audioStream);

            }

        }

        private void PlayAudioClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AudioPlayer.Play();
        }

    }
}
```

Cheers guys

Comment: Please narrow down the code to the relevant parts. Code with this amount of lines is hard to analyze.

Comment: Narrow down the code you're providing to only code only relevant to this issue. What have you tried? What specifically throws the exception? Based on what you've provided the only help I can offer is to not press the record button.

Answer (score 0):

So this is from the channel9 absolute beginner videos.  Full source for all samples can be found over at https://absolutebeginner.codeplex.com/

First I'd validate if you have the microphone capability flag set.  Next I'd compare your code against the code for the sample in that lesson.